# $G$ acts on $X$ with property: For any two ordered pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ there exist $g\in G$ st. $x'=x^g$ and $y'=y^g$. $G$ acts primitively?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ acts on $X$ with the property: For any two ordered pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ such that $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements in $X$, as well as $x'$ and $y'$, there exist $g\in G$ such that $x'=x^g$ and $y'=y^g$. Show that $G$ acts primitively on $X$.

We know that $G$ acts primitively on $X$ if:

1. $G$ acts transitively on $X$
2. all blocks are trivial

1. $\forall x,x'\in X, \exists g\in G$ st. $x'=x^g$, so transitivity follows by the definition?
2. Suppose $B$ is block and $|B|>1$. WTS: $B=X$
   $B^g=\{ x^g:x\in B \}=\{ x':x'\in X \}=X$. Similarly for $y$.

So it should be it, our action should be primitive, but somehow I'm sceptical about this. Does this make sense?

Comment: What does "WTS" mean?

Comment: It means Want To Show

Comment: The idea is, pick two distinct element $x, y \in B$. Now let $y' \ne x$ be an arbitrary element of $X$. Then there is $g$ such that $x^{g} = x$ and $y^{g} = y' \in B^{g}$. Now what can you say about $B \cap B^{g}$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti $x=x^g \in B^g, x\in B$ so $B\cap B^g=\{x\}$. But since $B$ is a block, then $B=B^g$. What else?

Comment: Groups satisfying your hypothesis are called 2-transitive or sometime doubly transitive. It is a standard result that 2-transitivity implies primitivity, but not particularly difficult so it can be done as an exercise. The problem is that you have not made any serious attempt to solve it. (Yes you are correct in saying that 2-transitivity implies transitivity.)